# Command line or bash method to copy the contents of file to itself

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a file named `fileName.txt` and the sample contents can be assumed as below:

```
first few lines to be ignored

abc
def
ghi
klm
```

I want a resultant file to look like this

```
first few lines to be ignored

abc
def
ghi
klm


abc
def
ghi
klm

abc
def
ghi
klm
```

I want to know a command-line method or bash method to replicate the lines (assuming that I know the line numbers) within the same file.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: How do you know which and how many lines have to be ignored ?

Comment: I want to copy based on the range of line numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can specify the lines to duplicate, then you can pick the lines from your file with `sed -n 'x,yp' file`, loop as many times as you care to duplicate them, then using redirection, write the duplicated lines to a temp-file. Then it is simply a matter of appending the temp-file to your original file. To duplicate lines `2-6` (twice), you could do something like:

```
(for i in {1..2}; do sed -n '2,6p' file; done) > mytmp && cat mytmp >> file
```

(**note:** the `(...) > mytmp` simply executes the loop in a subshell and then redirects all output from the subshell to `mytmp`)

Given your input file of:

```
$ cat file
first few lines to be ignored

abc
def
ghi
klm
```

The result duplicating lines 2-6 would be:

```
$ cat file
first few lines to be ignored

abc
def
ghi
klm

abc
def
ghi
klm

abc
def
ghi
klm
```

Let me know if that is what you had in mind.

Comment: You could use `tail -n +2 file | head -n 4` instead of `sed -n '2,6p' file` which is supposed to be faster (especially with huge file) according to [this unix stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47423) (not enough faster to be relevant with small files as in the example tho')

Comment: Yes, that is a good alternative. I'm sure there are 1/2 dozen ways to skin this cat, this was just the first that popped into mind. If it is a really huge file, `tail -n +2 file` still generates all lines in the file (except the first two), so I'm not sure it would be necessarily faster. At least with `sed` you are only picking lines 2-6 regardless of how many lines the original has. I'll have to play with both to see how it works out. Thanks.